# Lecture Notes for recalling Point Set Topology

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, reference-request, metric-spaces

I took 2 semester course on  point set topology, also studied it on my own and learned some basic algebraic topology from Hatcher's book. It has been a while since my last topology study. Now, I want to study some further topics in topology. I can still prove some basic theorems like "compactness is preserved under continuous functions". However, I do not remember how to approach more complicated theorems so I need a quick recap. I do not want to dive into a book-since I am not starting it from "0"- therefore I am looking for some lecture notes that can help me to see what is going on and gain some speed while doing proofs. Thank you.

Comment: Bredon's (topology and geometry) first chapter is an excellent recap and reference for the basics of topology.

Comment: @AloizioMacedo, Thank you, I am checking it now.

Comment: why not recap the points you aren't comfortable with as they come up in your further study?

Comment: @mt3, the lecture notes looks more "smooth" to me, on the other hand in a  reference book there are bunch of theorems, examples written in a small font that looks -in my conditions- unnecessarily complicated to  me.